# cakephp - Search through entire model and HasManys and using wildcards

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, search

I have a User model and 3 other models (HasManys) of user: Skill, Experience, Qualification

> public $hasMany = array(
>
> ```
>   'Experience' => array(...
>   'Qualification' => array(...
>   'Skill' => array(...
> ```

and each of the 3 models has

> public $belongsTo = array(
>           'User' => array(...

Skill, Experience, and Qualification both contain a field called "title" and "description"

What's the best way to wild card search (%search%) through each **OR** "title" and "description" of all 3 models and return users that match the criteria?

I'm having a really hard time getting my head around it, and whatever I search for is the opposite of what I want or just not relevant.

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve such a task?

I have something like this so far:

```
$cond=array('OR'=>array(
"Skills.name LIKE '%$keyword%'",
"Experiences.name LIKE '%$keyword%'", 
"Experiences.description LIKE '%$keyword%'")  
);

$conditions = array('conditions'=>$cond);
$list = $this->User->find('all', 
    array('conditions') => $cond);

$list = $this->User->find('all', array('recursive'=> 1, 'conditions'=> $cond));
```

Any help would really be appreciated as I've spent the good part of 5 hours looking and trying out different ways to literally no avail.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would filter each model using the 'keyword' condition and collect user-ids from that. Following this, use the list of user-ids to return a list of users. Something like;

```
// get distinct user-ids and simplify the results array with Hash::extract()
$userIds = Hash::extract($this->User->Skill->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('DISTINCT Skill.user_id'),
    'conditions' => array('Skill.name LIKE ?' => "%$keyword%"),
    'recursive' => -1
)), '{n}.User.id');

// repeat for the other tables, and merge the user-ids

.....


// Use the list of user-ids for retrieve matching users
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $userIds)));
```

However, depending on the amount of users, this may return a huge list of user-ids, which may not be ideal. In the end it's always possible to use a custom-query and execute that with model->query().

Comment: Thanks buddy, that worked a treat! However, I later discovered that I was over-thinking the problem, and I all I needed was `User->find('all'...` funny how those things turn out, huh.